# GCS to S3 transfer - improve speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

- We perform a weekly transfer from GCS to S3 using gsutil command below. 5,000 compressed objects, ~82 MB each - combined size of ~380 GB. It exports data to be used by Redshift, if that's of any relevance
- Same kind of transfer from an on-prem Hadoop cluster to S3 took under 1 hour. Now with gsutil, it takes 4-5 hours.
- I'm aware that, under the hood, gsutil downloads the files from GCS and then uploads them to S3 which adds some overhead. So, hoping for faster speeds, I've tried executing gsutil on Compute Engine in the geographical location of S3 and GCS buckets but it was equally slow
- I've played with parallel_process_count and parallel_thread_count parameters but it made no difference

  ```
  gsutil -m rsync -r -n GCS_DIR S3_DIR
  ```

My questions are:

- Is there anything else I can do to speed it up?
- What combinations of parallel_process_count and parallel_thread_count would you try?
- Is there any way to find out which stage creates the bottleneck (if any)? I.e. is it upload or download stage?
- Looking at logs, does below mean that bandwidth is at 0% for a period of time?

  ```
  Copying gcs://**s3.000000004972.gz 
  [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]... 
  [4.8k/5.0k files][367.4 GiB/381.6 GiB]  96% Done     0.0 B/s
  ```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you use [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview#should_you_use_gsutil_or) to transfer objects from GCS to S3? This is the preferred method for your use case.

Comment: Storage Transfer Service can only be used to load _from_ S3. It doesn't let you export data _to_ S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal values for parallel_process_count and parallel_thread_count depend on  network speed, number of CPUs and available memory - it's [recommended](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions#options) that you experiment a bit to find the optimal values.

You might try using [perfdiag](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag) to get more information about the bucket on Google Cloud's side - it's a command that runs a suite of diagnostic tests for a given bucket.

The output you've shared indicates that no upload is happening for some period of time, perhaps due to the way gsutil chunks the uploads.

As a final recommendation for speeding up your transfers to Amazon, you might try using [Apache Beam / Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/).